# How to %load a script in ipython without printing code to the screen?

Tags: python, ipython

I'm running ipython through an ssh terminal. `%load` in ipython prints the code to the screen. Is there a way of loading a script while surpressing the verbosity (preferably with few keystrokes)?

Comment: Why not just.... `import` it?

Comment: redirect stdout ? https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/redirecting-all-kinds-of-stdout-in-python/

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `%load`, instead type `%run`. From their docstrings:

`%load` Load code into the current frontend.

`%run` Run the named file inside IPython as a program.

Comment: %run without -i will not see the session's variables, so the code needs to include all the definitions and initializations, which is not how %load does it.